# changing datagridview selection color dynamically c#

Tags: winforms, datagridview

the problem is that when i change the color of selected row by RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor in my form constructor it works but it does not work in button events when user clicks some button for changing grid selected back color!
any help please!

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor=Color.Red; //this      works fine
}
void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor=Color.Blue;//but this does not work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender,
    DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
  If (DatagridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Selected )
  {

     DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor=Color.Blue;

  }
}
```

Comment: @IsaacShakiba .. Sorrrryy !! Copy paste error from your code :P.. Its' updated ..try again ..

Comment: i don't want to change the selection back color temporary!

Answer (score 0):

```
void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
       row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue
   }
}
```

Update :

```
void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
   {
       col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
   }
}
```

Comment: this code change the selection color of existing rows,when a row is added to grid the selection back color changes to default color!